# Google Cloud Datastore with and w/o Protocol Buffers

Tags: google-app-engine, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-datastore

While searching for information about the Google Cloud Datastore, I stumbled upon two different official documentation branches that seem to have the same content in terms of concepts, but provide code samples based on two different APIs:

1. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/) examples are based on the Protocol Buffers API.
2. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) the same content is provided with examples based on the standard Google App Engine SDK.

Seems like the same set of actions are supported by both the APIs, but I'm not able to figure out what are the substantial differences between the two. Why should I choose one instead of the other, and why Google is offering both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is where your application will run. Datastore started as an App Engine-only thing, with App Engine-specific APIs, and was later expanded to support access from other sources.

If you're deploying to Google App Engine, choose #2.

If you're deploying elsewhere, and want to use Google Cloud Datastore as your repository, choose #1.